# Proper subgroup of a finite $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I am a beginner to $p$-groups and have the following question at hand:

> Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of a finite $p$-group $G$. If $|H|=p^s$ , then there exists a subgroup of order $p^{s+1}$ containing $H$.

My thoughts:

I think Quotient groups will come handy here. But I am nit being able to use it. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: Prove that $H$ is a proper subgroup of its normalizer.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Done. After that?

Comment: After that you work a bit more to finish the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $N_G[H]$, the normalizer of $H$ in $G$.  Since $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G[H]$, we can consider the factor group $N_G[H]/H$.  Note that $p$ divides $\left | N_G[H]/H \right|$ so $N_G[H]/H$ has a subgroup of order $p$.  This subgroup is of the form $K/H$ where $K$ is a subgroup of $N_G[H]$ containing $H$.  Then $|K| = |H|(K:H) = p^sp = p^{s+1}$ as desired.

Comment: I know this may look silly, but still: Can you say exactly why $p$ divides $|N_G[H]/H|$? Is $N_G[H]$ a $p-$subgroup?

Comment: No questions are silly!  If $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ then $(N_G[H] : H) \equiv (G : H)$ mod $p$.  Since $p$ divides $(G : H)$, $p$ must also divide $(N_G[H]:H)$. (Remember that $| N_G[H] / H | = (N_G[H] : H)$.)

Comment: Please, why do we have $[N_G(H) : H] \equiv [G : H] \pmod p$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Define $G'=G/H$. $|G'|=|G|/|H|\implies G$ is a $p-$group. $\therefore\exists$ a normal subgroup of order $p$ in $G'$ (Say $K'$).

Let $\psi$ be the canonical projection $\psi:G\rightarrow G'$.

Define  $$K=\psi^{-1}(K')=\{g\in G:gH\in K'\}$$
$\therefore K'=K/ H\implies |K|=|K'||H|=p\times p^s=p^{s+1}$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: No, this proof is not correct because the subgroup $H$ might not be normal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay. I get it.So how to prove?