# Does $p$ always divide $[N_G(H) : H]$ when $G$ is a $p$-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

On [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938098/proper-subgroup-of-a-finite-p-group), $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

The accepted answer says

> Note that p divides $|N_G[H]/H|$ so $N_G[H]/H$ has a subgroup of order $p$.

But what about if $H$ were equal to its own normalizer, $N_G(H)$? In that case, $|N_G[H]/H|$ would be $1$, hence, not divisible by $p$.

Is there any result that prevents a proper subgroup of being equal to its normalizer considering that they are $p$-groups?

Or do you know how to prove that quoted preposition?

Comment: Hint: Any nontrivial $p$-group has a nontrivial center.

Comment: Most probably they're using the well known result that in finite $\;p\,$- groups, any non-trivial subgroup is *properly* contained in its normalizer. This much is true for general nilpotent groups.

Comment: In principle your concern is valid. However, in finite $p$-groups any proper subgroup is strictly contained in its normalizer so $p$ does indeed divide the index in question.

Comment: Nilpotent groups (not necessarliy finite) share the prinicple of "normalizers grow", which essentially means that for a proper subgroup, its normalizer strictly contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that this question does not remain listed as unanswered, here is an explanation.

We have a $p$-group $G$ and a proper subgroup $H$ of $G$. Finite $p$-groups have a property known as the normaliser condition. This condition says that every proper subgroup is *strictly* contained in its normaliser. Hence $H < N_{G}(H)$. Since we are in a $p$-group, the index must be some power of $p$ and we have said above it is not trivial and so we must have $[N_{G}(H):H]=p^{i}$ with $i \geq 1$.

Now briefly I will give an outline of one way to see why the normaliser condition holds and give some references.

Finite $p$-groups satisfy a condition known as [nilpotency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group). 
Using the fact that a group $G$ is nilpotent, you can show that [every proper $H$ of $G$ is subnormal in $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047124/subgroups-of-nilpotent-groups-are-subnormal). This then implies the [normaliser condition](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_satisfying_normalizer_condition).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because then $H$ is in turn a $p$-group, and hence $[G:H]\equiv [N_G(H):H]\pmod p$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4409385/1007416)). But in this case, $[G:H]\equiv 0\pmod p$ either, whence the claim follows.